# Presenting multiple view controller modally -- A memory issue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

How much memory a view controller eats when it is loaded into the memory?

I have an application where I am planning to keep 4 view controllers in the memory as they are modal on each other and out of them, one view controller is a navigation controller (with 4-5 view controller pushed in stack) presented as modal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A view controller object itself usually needs very little memory unless you use it store large objects like images or caches. What takes a lot of memory is the view that is attached to the view controller. That's why view controllers unload their views when they receive a memory warning and the view is not currently on screen.

So you shouldn't worry. Follow the memory management rules, implement `viewDidUnload` correctly (release your outlets) and respond to memory warnings appropriately. The view controllers will take care of unloading and reloading their views if needed.